# Assigning two models of the same type to another model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I've got an interesting problem in rails
Let's say i have a model and i'd like to attach two other models to it, of the same type,
but these two should be seperated.

Let's say we have a dog, and a dog can have trainers, as well as an owner, but trainers and owners are both part of the human table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose dog table has owner_id and trainer_id which is reference to foreign key

```
class Dog <AR::Base
 belongs_to :trainer,:class_name=>"Human",:foreign_key=>'trainer_id'
 belongs_to :owner,:class_name=>"Human",:foreign_key=>'owner_id'
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that did the job. Thanks for the quick answer. Much appreciated :)